# How to invoke some method on Bootstrap Vue <b-modal> X-close button

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal

Using **b-modal** Bootstrap Vue component, I'am trying to invoke especific method when the user clicks on the **'X' button** at the right corner of the modal window.

I've tried with *@close*, *@closeHeader*, *@closeheader* without success.

```
<b-modal ok-only @ok="methodOk" @close="methodClose">
    <span>Window closed</span>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@close` event is what you're after.

If it isn't working for you, i suggest you check your version of BootstrapVue, or potential errors in your console.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClose() {
      alert('Modal X button pressed');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-btn v-b-modal.my-modal>Open Modal</b-btn>
  <b-modal id="my-modal" @close="onClose">
    Click the `X` top right to see an alert.
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: @close works. But not with the dependencies we are using:  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^1.5.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",

Comment: Yeah, makes sense if you're using BootstrapVue 1. That's quite old at this point. You can download the BootstrapVue repo on GitHub for the release you're using and run the docs locally to avoid issues. As you might experience a lot of things don't work when using the current docs.